# setWidget atribute error on pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I'm starting at python3+pyqt5 by doing a very silly .ui called invest.ui that has a single button "ok_button" that closes the interface when clicked. But I couldn't get the interface running when I run the following code:

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("invest.ui")

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def close(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invest.py", line 24, in <module>
    window = MyApp()
  File "invest.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
  File "<string>", line 37, in setupUi
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'setWidget'
```

How do I solve that, The attribute SetWidget has to be stated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you cited there is no `attribute 'setWidget'`,
therefore, I do not have such an error.

But there is an error:
`QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`

> QWidget::close()
>
> Closes this widget. Returns true if the widget was closed; otherwise returns false.

Try it:

**main.py**

```
import sys
#import time
#import datetime
#import random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("invest.ui")

class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # try it:        
        # self.ui.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        # or 
        self.ui.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.myClose)

#    def close(self):
#        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
    def myClose(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**invest.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>320</width>
    <height>240</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>31</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>92</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="ok_button">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>100</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Click me</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>92</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>32</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solve the problem, I just started a new ui and it worked so I don't know what was the problem with the .ui file